# How to set click whole area of point icon?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I use cluster for points:

```
 const clusterSource = new Cluster({
    distance: this.configService.config.distanceCluster || 100,
    source,
  });

  const clusterVector = new VectorLayer({
    source: clusterSource,
    style: (feature, resolution) =>
      this.styleFeatureFunction(feature, icon),
  });
```

Styles is:

```
  styleFeatureFunction = (feature, icon, options?: any) => {
    const size = feature.get('features').length;

    if (icon) {
      const style = new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
          anchor: icon.anchor,
          scale: icon.scale,
          color: options?.color || icon.color,
          src: `./assets/images/${icon.src}`,
        }),
      });

      const { text } = icon;

      if (text) {
        let textvalue: string;

        if (text.seq) textvalue = size + '';
        if (text.text) textvalue = text.text;

        const styleText = new Text();

        if (text.stroke) {
          const stroke = new Stroke({ color: text.stroke });
          if (text.StrokeWidth) stroke.setWidth(text.StrokeWidth);
          styleText.setStroke(stroke);
        }

        if (text.fill)
          styleText.setFill(
            new Fill({
              color: text.fill,
            })
          );

        if (text.font) styleText.setFont(text.font);
        if (text.scale) styleText.setScale(text.scale);
        if (textvalue) styleText.setText(textvalue);

        style.setText(styleText);
      }

      return style;
    }
  };
```

Problem is click works only by text inside point. How to listn click by whole pointer (icon)?

**I made this trick** in `styleFeatureFunction = (feature, icon, options?: any) => {}` and it works:

```
return [
        style, // Prev styles
        new Style({ // New styles with transparent circle
          image: new Circle({
            radius: 45,
            fill: new Fill({ color: 'transparent' }),
          }),
        }),
      ];
```

But I am not sure that is correct way